# how to interrupt command initramfs

Tags: initramfs, interrupt

I have made a huge mistake. I'm currently loaded into initramfs, trying to fix an error similar to [this post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/589899/missing-modules-cat-proc-modules-ls-dev-and-uuid-doesnt-exist-in-busybox). I decided to `cat /dev/XXXX`, where I'm pretty sure `XXXX` is the main partition where Ubuntu is installed. It's like 300+ GB. So now it's just printing constantly to the screen (mostly gibberish).  I apparently have no way to interrupt, nor even to hard-reset the computer (presumably because the power button doesn't work in initramfs). Every time I've needed to reset the computer previously, I've had to use `poweroff -f`... obviously that's not an option. Any amount of `ctrl + c`, `ctrl + z`, `ctrl + \`, etc., doesn't seem to work. Any suggestions other than just letting my computer run until it either finishes `cat`ing, or the battery dies?

edit: if it wasn't clear, this is on a laptop, so I can't even directly unplug the power supply without opening the thing up, which would be super dangerous anyway

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally holding the power button down for at least 4 seconds should force the power to switch off (it's implemented in hardware), but on laptops, there might be a separate "forced power off" button that needs an untwisted paperclip or a similar tool to press.

Knowing the exact model of your laptop would help greatly in finding an answer to this question.

What you're seeing is a side effect of the computer reading data from disk much, **much** faster than it can display in text form. Even though Ctrl+C should technically work, the problem is that there is just so much data already read and "in the pipeline" going to the display that you won't be seeing the effect of the keyboard interrupt very soon.

Comment: Thanks, looked up force shutdown and that helped, thanks so much!