# Ubuntu is not booting in dual boot system

Tags: ubuntu, dual-boot

After selecting Ubuntu from grub menu, my Ubuntu 20 is not booting. Instead, it shows the below screen:
[image]

Please advise. Because I need to recover some files from my Ubuntu 20 OS.

Comment: Have you flashed your BIOS between now and the time that Ubuntu was booting properly?

Comment: I do not even know what is it. But I made firmware updates as recommended by dell.

Comment: Updating firmware resets many UEFI settings to defaults on most systems. If you changed settings to install Ubuntu, you need to look in UEFI and review all those settings and probably have to redo most.

Comment: I concur with @oldfred. See if you can disable Secure Boot in UEFI settings. I read that someone had this same issue, and [needed to change SATA settings](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/613936/407880).

Comment: So do I need to use a bootable USB drive again or I just change the BIOS settings and then ubuntu will be able to boot again?

Comment: You have to try suggestions, and then report what works or what did not work.

Comment: Thanks, everyone. From BIOS settings I changed the SATA operation mode from RAID to AHCI. Now Ubuntu is booting successfully.